# ASP dynamic multi-dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, asp-classic

new to ASP. Trying to create a multi-dimensional array from a form. In php it would be like

```
<?php 
    $myArray = array();
    for($i = 0 $i< $myArray.size() $i++){ 

    myArray[$i] = array(field1=>"var1",field2=>var2);
    }
?> //syntax not exactly correct but you get the picture
```

I have to do similar in ASP but I can seem to figure it out, though it should be simple

I need to get values in from my form in rows which I have done
then I need to put the values into the array

```
Function getResults(totalRows)

dim results() 'my array for results
for i = 0 to totalRows - 1 

color = request.form("color"&i)
width = request.form("width"&i)
height = request.form("height"&i)


results(i)("color") = color
results(i)("height") = height
results(i)("width") =  width

response.write("color is " &results(i)("color")
response.write("color is " &results(i)("height")
response.write("color is " &results(i)("width")
NEXT
```

End Function

I need to return this array to work with it, thanks in advance, I have tried looking online but can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 5):

problem solved, I used incorrect syntax, and had to reDim the array  - just in-case this helps somebody else

```
 dim results() 'my array for results
 ReDim Results(totalRows, 3)
 for i = 0 to totalRows - 1 
   results(i,0) = color
   results(i,1) = height
   results(1,2) =  width

   response.write("color is " &results(i,0)
   response.write("color is " &results(i,1)
   response.write("color is " &results(i,2)
NEXT
```

you could substitute the second index within another loop,